# In which of the three topologies does $X$ have a countable basis?

Tags: general-topology, first-countable

[image]

**Question: In which of the three topologies does $X$ have a countable basis?**

Below is the way I did....Can someone verify my proof ? Let me know if there is any concern or questions.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $\Bbb R^2$ is separable metric, so all of its subspaces are second countable; these should be standard facts.
2. In the railroad metric, we again have a metric space that is $\sigma$-compact (as all $S_n$ are compact) and so Lindelöf and second countable. I don't really get what you're going for with your attempt.
3. Show that at $v=(0,1)$, the space in the coherent topology is not first countable (this can be shown using a diagonalisation argument), so the total space cannot be second countable either.

Comment: I understand that $T_s$ and $T_r$ are second countable, i.e. they have a countable basis but I didnt get $T_c$ (coherent topology), why it does not have a countable basis ?  "Diagonalisation argument" ?? are you talking abt cantor's diagonalisation ?

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun it uses the idea of it. Assume a countable local base and find an open subset such that none of the countable sets sits inside it.

Comment: @Henno....I am sorry to say that we didnt do Cantor's diagonalisation since we didnt do this in class. Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: @Henno...Assume a countable local base and find an open subset such that none of the countable sets sits inside it- are you trying to prove Lindeof theorem (If X has a countable base for its topology, prove that any open cover of X contains a countable subcover) ??

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun no, not at all.

Comment: @Henno....We shall prove that $v(0,1)$ dosen't have countable basis in $T_c$. Suppose it has and let there exist $B_1$,$B_2$, $B_3$,......Since each $B_n$ is open, this implies that $B_n \cap S_n$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is open. So, take a point $y_n$ that belongs to the intersection of $B_n$ and $S_n$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $S_n$' be the line joining $v(0,1)$ and $y_n$. It should not contain $y_n$. Let $C_n$ = union of all $S_n$'. Then $C_n$' is open In $X$ but no $B_n$ is contained in it, which is a contradiction since we assumed at the beginning that it has a countable basis....

Comment: .......therefore, we have proved that $v = (0,1)$ in $T_c$ doesn't have a countable basis. Kindly check my arguments n lemme know if this looks correct n accurate. Help me if u think it needs a change somewhere. appreciate ur help & support.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun yes, this is indeed the idea. Note that $O:=\bigcup_n S'_n$ does not depend on $n$ any more (that's the whole point) but that for all $n: y_n \in B_n\setminus O$, showing that for all $n$, $B_n \subseteq O$ is false, and as $O$ is an open neighbourhood of $v$, this contrdicts the local base property. You use the $n$'th "stalk" $S'_n$ to "kill" $B_n$ as a local base set, as it where. You see the similarity with Cantor's argument?

Comment: @Henno.....I got it now, your "whole point" statement basically cleared my doubt & confusion I was facing. So i am good now. Regarding cantor's argument like I said I havent done that in class, so I will surely try to look up on google and see how it goes. but thanks a lot for helping me on this, appreciate ur help sir. :)

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun you’re welcome!